# Define bash function which does not show up in xtrace (set -x)

Tags: bash, function, debugging, tracing

In a bash script I have a `log()` function that is used in several places, as well as a `logs()` function that diverts lots of line to `log()`. When I run parts of the script with `set -x`, obviously all commands within `logs()` and `log()` are traced too.

I would like to define `logs()` and `log()` such that at least their content, at best even their call is suppressed from `set -x` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty hack that should work in all shells is to (temporarily) make your `log` an external script instead of a function.

In bash you could also use a `trap '...' DEBUG` and `shopt -s extdebug` combination, which is much more versatile than `set -x`. Example:

```
debug() {
        local f=${FUNCNAME[1]} d=${#FUNCNAME[@]} c=$BASH_COMMAND
        if [ "$NOTRACE" ]; then
                case $debug_skip in ''|$d) debug_skip=;; *) return;; esac
                eval "case \$c in $NOTRACE) debug_skip=\$d; return; esac"
        fi

        # before the 1st command in a function XXX
        case $c in $f|"$f "*) return;; esac

        printf >&2 "%*s(%s) %s\n" $((d * 2 - 4)) "" "$f" "$c"
}
```

(Of course, you can dispense with the strange format + indenting and make it completely `set-x`-like; you can also redirect it to another file instead of mixed with the stderr from commands.)

Then:

```
NOTRACE='"log "*'
shopt -s extdebug
trap debug DEBUG

log(){ log1 "$@"; }; log1(){ log2 "$@"; }
log2(){ log3 "$@"; }; log3(){ echo "$@"; }

foo(){ foo1 "$@"; }; foo1(){ foo2 "$@"; }
foo2(){ foo3 "$@"; }; foo3(){ echo "$@"; }

bar(){ case $# in 0) ;; *) echo "$1"; shift; bar "$@";; esac; }

foo 1 2 3
log 7 8 9
bar 1 2 3 4
```

will result in:

```
(main) foo 1 2 3
  (foo) foo1 "$@"
    (foo1) foo2 "$@"
      (foo2) foo3 "$@"
        (foo3) echo "$@"
1 2 3
7 8 9
(main) bar 1 2 3 4
  (bar) case $# in
  (bar) echo "$1"
1
  (bar) shift
    (bar) case $# in
    (bar) echo "$1"
2
    (bar) shift
      (bar) case $# in
      (bar) echo "$1"
3
      (bar) shift
        (bar) case $# in
        (bar) echo "$1"
4
        (bar) shift
          (bar) case $# in
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change how the function is invoked from inside the function, but you could define the function to invoke a subshell which then immediately turns off tracing; notice the parenthesis surrounding the body instead of the typical braces:

```
log() (
  set +x
  # rest of log()
)
```

Invoking `log()` then generates only the call itself (from the existing `set -x` code) and the `set +x` call, not the rest of the subsequent commands in the function. The existing `set -x` setting is restored once the function exits.

Comment: You do need to set it back on at the end of log().

Comment: Are you sure? The function is defined to run in a subshell (the second set of parenthesis), so the local settings there go away with that shell.

Answer (score 1):

To suppress xtrace output, just use `set -x`. To turn it back on, use `set -x`. To detect if it's on, use `shopt -q -o xtrace`. eg

```
log() {
  if shopt -q -o xtrace; then TRACE_IS_ON=yes; else TRACE_IS_ON=no; fi
  set +x # turn xtrace off
  ...
  [[ "$TRACE_IS_ON" == "yes" ]] && set +x
}
```

There's still some 'chatter' but that's the best I can do. To supress seeing the calls to log() you can surround each call to log() with a similar code instead of inside the function.

Comment: `set -x` does not suppress xtrace output, `set +x` does.