# Bash shell examples for t and f parameters on declare command

Tags: shell-script

I don't understand t and f parameters on declare command exactly why and how they are used.
Would you please give me a few simple illustrations?

Comment: Parameters to what?

Comment: declare command @ilkkachu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `trace` attribute makes the function in question inherit the `DEBUG` and `RETURN` traps. `-f` just means that the argument to `declare` is a function, and not a variable.

Bash's manual says this [about functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions):

> All other aspects of the shell execution environment  are identical between a function and its caller with these exceptions: the DEBUG and RETURN traps are not inherited unless the function has been given the trace attribute

And the [description of `declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare):

> `-t`     Give each name the trace attribute.  Traced functions inherit the DEBUG and RETURN traps from the calling shell.  The trace attribute has no special meaning for variables.

Here's what happens with a function *without* the `trace` attribute:

```
$ f() { echo a; echo b; }
$ trap 'echo DEBUG: $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
$ f
DEBUG: f
a             
b
```

And here's what happens when the function is given the `trace` attribute.

```
$ declare -f -t f
DEBUG: declare -f -t f
$ f
DEBUG: f      
DEBUG: f
DEBUG: echo a 
a      
DEBUG: echo b 
b
```

(I have no idea why the function call shows up twice in the trap.)

Comment: from the `trap` entry in the bash(1) manpage (emphasis mine): " If a `sigspec` is `DEBUG`, the `command` arg is executed before every simple command, `for`  command,  `case`  command,
              `select`  command,  every  arithmetic  `for` command, **and before the
              first command executes in a shell function**"

Comment: if you want to make the difference between the two, you could use the `FUNCNAME` array, as in my kludge [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495400/308316). Better ideas are welcome ;-)